# How to get exact OmanTime?

Tags: sql-server

how to get the exact OmanTime using an sql function?

This is my code : 
RETURN DATEADD(mi,-90,@CurrentDate)

but it is not correct.

Comment: Can you show whole code? I suppose it is function.

Answer (score 1):

Muscat, Oman in is the +4 timezone, so local time there is 4 hours later than UTC - thus, when it's noon on the zero meridian it's 4:00 PM in Muscat.  Thus, you'd need to do something like

```
RETURN DATEADD(Hour, 4, GETUTCDATE())
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Note that this only works because that timezone has no daylight savings time. For timezones that do, it gets rather more complex.

Comment: SELECT DATEADD(Hour, 4, GETUTCDATE())  will work,but RETURN DATEADD(Hour, 4, GETUTCDATE()) is not working.
The error message is "Invalid use of 'getutcdate' within a function"

Comment: SELECT DATEADD(Hour, 4, GETUTCDATE()) will work,but RETURN DATEADD(Hour, 4, GETUTCDATE()) is not working. The error message is "Invalid use of 'getutcdate' within a function"